# Create Repository using redis in SpringBoot App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, repository-pattern

I have a object:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ResultGeoObjectDto {
   private String addressLine;
   private String location;
   private double latitude;
   private double longitude;
}
```

I created a service, which work with my Object and `Redis`:

```
@Service
public class RedisService {

private final RedisTemplate<String, List<ResultGeoObjectDto>> redisTemplate;

@Autowired
public RedisService(RedisTemplate<String, List<ResultGeoObjectDto>> redisTemplate) {
    this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
}

public void setValue(String key, List<ResultGeoObjectDto> value) {

    redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPush(key, value);
}

public List<ResultGeoObjectDto> getGeoObjectByKey(String key) {
    return redisTemplate.opsForList().range(key, -1, -1).get(0);
}

public boolean objectExistInRedisStore(String key) {
    return redisTemplate.hasKey(key);
}
```

}

This works great, but many examples use a `Repository` pattern. Can you tell me how to make a repository?

For example [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial) using a static key, and I have it dynamically formed. And also I have a List of objects, instead of one. I can not understand how I need to do the right architecture.

Comment: The link you share is already cover everything. If you want dynamic key you just need to implement your repository methods take key argument with object too. By the way in the linked tutorial key is like a table name. Your dynamic key is equal to student's id in the tutorial and it is ofcourse dynamic.
If you use your objects indivually, saving list is a bad practice. But if your business logic is that way saving list is ok. But if i were you, i would encapsulate that list of object in an upper class and save this class's objects.

Answer (score 7):

Using Redis Repository is very easy, and it's much better than using RedisTemplate for persisting data.

Here is the example:

1. Annotate Entity

   ```
   @RedisHash("persons")
   public class Person {
       @Id String id;
       String firstname;
       String lastname;
       Address address;
   }
   ```
2. Create Redis Repository interface

   ```
   public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {}
   ```
3. Configuration

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableRedisRepositories
   public class ApplicationConfig {
     @Bean
     public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
     return new JedisConnectionFactory();
     }
     @Bean
     public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
     RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]>();
     return template;
     }
   }
   ```
4. Call CRUD operations.

   ```
   @Autowired PersonRepository repo;
   public void basicCrudOperations() {
     Person rand = new Person("rand", "al'thor");
     rand.setAddress(new Address("emond's field", "andor"));
     repo.save(rand); ①
     repo.findOne(rand.getId()); ②
     repo.count(); ③
     repo.delete(rand); ④
   }
   ```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories